# How to webscrape this website using Jsoup with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tyB6.png)]

I recently started my Android dev path and I've been having some troubles with webscraping. I don't really understand it and I was wondering how should I do this. Basically in the picture I presented there is a table of data about all animal shelters in Croatia. I want to webscrape all names(Naziv Sklonista), adresses(adresa sklonista) and cities(naselje) and store them in a data class AnimalShelters. I was told that I could use Jsoup with that but I can't really understand how to. And since I only have the adress of a shelter I would need to use geocoding to really be able to put a marker on the google map. I also need to mention that I can scroll with the bar that I marked with number 2 and there's more data in the table and there's also 3 pages in the table. This is the link of the website "https://jic.mps.hr/sklonista/#!sklonista".

I read some articles and watched some youtube videos about Jsoup with Kotlin and really webscraping and how I need to use the inspect element to really see the HTML so I could webscrape the information I want but I've been having troubles with understanding it.
(Also if someone could list me some really good tools for  learning app dev with kotlin I would really appreciate it because I'm having a hard time)

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkplG.png)]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a site for suggestions about learning to code (it's considered off-topic) so you probably won't gte any help with that. Honestly you're probably best doing something like the Google Codelabs stuff to get the hang of coding in Kotlin, and developing apps in general, before you start adding stuff like learning to webscrape in the mix. It's a lot if you're new!

---

The basic way you use Jsoup is to use things like *selectors* to [isolate the specific elements you want](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). The *Developer Tools* in a web browser are very helpful for this - press *F12* on that site and you can see the HTML being displayed, you can click elements to find them in the HTML, and you can do *Ctrl+F* in the HTML display to type selector queries (like you'd use in Jsoup) and see what gets selected.

In your code you're searching for `div.shelter` which is a `div` element that has a *`shelter` class* (`.shelter`). I can't see one on the page (try searching for it!) but what you probably *do* want is that `table` element with the class `v-table-table`.

You want all the rows from that - they have different class names (since they're styled differently on alternate rows) but you could just grab all the `tr` elements inside the table. A selector that does that is `table.v-table-table tr`, i.e. *"all the `tr` elements that are descendants of that `table`"*.

And once you have the rows, those each contain a bunch of `td` elements that correspond to the different cells in the row. So you can pull out the items from that list you want (e.g. the second one) and use those. There's still a bunch of HTML in there, other nested elements, but if you just want the text content you can call `.text()` on the cell element and it'll give you whatever it eventually contains. That's the basics of how it works, but it really helps if you're familiar with HTML and DOM trees and selectors and all that.

---

**Unfortunately** websites aren't always well-behaved, and Jsoup only works with HTML. Your site has a couple of issues.

The first is when I use Jsoup to `connect` to the site, the text I get back is an error message, not the contents I see in a browser. It says:

```
You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.
```

This is the limitation with Jsoup - it's a parser, not a web browser. It doesn't have Javascript functionality, and a lot of websites rely on it to work. Your page buttons also work through Javascript, and they don't load a new URL that includes the page number (which you could use in the `connect` call to load a different page), so it would be very difficult to request those too without being able to execute the Javascript on the page number clicks.

To do this kind of thing, you actually need that browser functionality. You could try [HtmlUnit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/) (I've never used it) which is supposed to *emulate* a browser, or you could use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) (I've used this one) which actually *runs a browser you choose* and interacts with it programmatically - i.e. you're automating the browsing and the clicks. And then you can pull the HTML being displayed, and use Jsoup to parse it (or the Selenium library itself lets you do some basic parsing, it might be enough for what you need).

So yeah, more to learn! And this stuff can be tricky to get working and also learn how to do it all. Whoever said you can "just use Jsoup" was wrong unfortunately (although at a glance it looks like it would be fine). Good luck though! The question is probably going to get closed so I'm posting this as some general advice of where to go next

Answer (score 1):

Just made a quick test with HtmlUnit and it looks like [HtmlUnit](https://www.htmlunit.org/) (3.1.0) is able to handle this pages also including switching to the next page.

There is also a special [version for Android](https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android) (this is more a special package of the same software to avoid some problems)